# NilLiteralConvertible in Property setter

Tags: swift, properties

In swift I have this:

```
 ///3.5.1.8 Range is ± 32,576 FPM, FPM of 32640 means max.  Also can be invalid (nil)
var vVelcotiy: Int? {
    get {

        let ret : Int16 = decode12Bit2sCompliment(bytes[15], bytes[16], useEntireFirstByte: false)

        return Int(ret * 64);
    }
    set {

        if (bytes[15] == 8 && bytes[16] == 0) {
            return nil
        }

        if let n = newValue {
            let nv = n / 64
            bytes[15] = (bytes[15] & 0xF0) | (UInt8(nv) >> 8)
            bytes[16] = UInt8(nv)

        } else {
            bytes[15] = (bytes[15] & 0xF0) | 0xF8
            bytes[16] = 0x00
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error of `type '()' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'` but I've declared my property as optional so I'm confused.

I'm hoping to be able to do:

`var a : vVelocity = nil`

Comment: Given your implementation, there's no way your property can ever have a nil value (it always returns `Int(ret * 64)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading rintaro's answer and taking my comment into consideration, I think you've misplaced the first check in the setter, it looks like it belongs in the getter instead:

```
var vVelcotiy: Int? {
    get {
        if (bytes[15] == 8 && bytes[16] == 0) {
            return nil
        }

        let ret : Int16 = decode12Bit2sCompliment(bytes[15], bytes[16], useEntireFirstByte: false)

        return Int(ret * 64);
    }
    set {

        if let n = newValue {
            let nv = n / 64
            bytes[15] = (bytes[15] & 0xF0) | (UInt8(nv) >> 8)
            bytes[16] = UInt8(nv)

        } else {
            bytes[15] = (bytes[15] & 0xF0) | 0xF8
            bytes[16] = 0x00
        }
    }
}
```

Now your getter has a possibility of returning nil, and your setter doesn't depend on the existing value.

Comment: DUH! ... Can't believe i missed that one... oye

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
set {
    if (bytes[15] == 8 && bytes[16] == 0) {
        return nil // <--- HERE
    }
```

You cannot return anything from `set { }`. If you want to break, just `return` instead.

```
set {
    if (bytes[15] == 8 && bytes[16] == 0) {
        return
    }
```

Comment: I think (read my comment above) that this check actually got transcribed from his getter to his setter, it reads more like it belongs there, and at that point, `return nil` is appropriate.  And it would solve the "can never return nil" issue.

Comment: @David most likely :)